# why the android studio did not open the flutter folder as a project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Today when I open the flutter project using android studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1, the IDE just load some files. Seems did not treated as the folder as a flutter project. The UI file structure look like this:

[image]

I am sure the flutter+dart plugin installed, why would this happen? what should I do to fix it and make it load flutter project success? I have tried Invalid Cache and Restart but it seems did not work.

Comment: Please check the android studio plugin. And then flutter is installed or not.

Comment: I deleted the .idea folder and fix it. @HasibAkon But I still did not know why would this happen.

Comment: Maybe it a cached issue.